# Unambiguous summation notation

Tags: summation, notation

Is there a way to unambiguously express which term is inside a summation and which one not? Are there any universally used conventions? 
For example let's say a want to sum terms $x_j$ and $E_1$ over $j$ and 
add to them $E_2$. Consider that the terms $E_1$, $E_2$ can be expressions that are independent of $j$ and not necessarily constants (they can be summations themselves over another index).
Some alternatives are

1. $\sum_j (x_j + E_1) + E_2$
2. $[\sum_j x_j + E_1] + E_2$
3. $[\sum_j (x_j + E_1)] + E_2$

The third one is certainly unambiguous but too verbose I think.

Comment: I think the first is reasonably clear.  The second is ambiguous because even with the brackets it's not clear whether the $C_{1}$ is included in the sum or not.

Comment: Personally, I use #1. Its natural since we  read $f(x)$ as "f of x", and thus read $\sum _j (x_j +C_1)$ as "sum of $x_j+C_1$" If you want a really good discussion of Sum notation see Knuths "Concrete Mathematics" chapter 2. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiop_SS65jUAhVk0YMKHQPcDF8QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.csie.ntu.edu.tw%2F~r97002%2Ftemp%2FConcrete%2520Mathematics%25202e.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGZfDyCyrw3dJeXf65P4gRi9ff1Og.

Comment: I shudder at all but the first option, although the third one is also ok. There are some arguably objective problems with the second, as has been pointed out.

Comment: Best option is $C_2 + \sum_j(x_j + C_1)$.

Comment: @DMcMor By the same token if $C_1$ is 0 (absent) it is not clear if $C_2$ is part of the summation, unless that is the case by convention.

Comment: @T. Gunn $C_2$ could be a summation over another index so that doesn't really change the problem.

Comment: @EvanRosica Thank you for the link. Discussion is interesting but unfortunately didn't find something that answers my question. Did I miss it?

Comment: @konpsych Knuth gives the definition on page 23, (and the linearity property on pg 30 (which is really 3 properties, of which my answer uses one)).  Since the notation is only defined as taking $\sum _k a_k$  its implicit that the only thing in the summand is the first term after it $a_k$. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: @EvanRosica I am not sure you can use a parenthesis after $\sum$ or $\prod$ with the same meaning as after a function. For instance, consider "$\prod_j (a_j+b_j) c$". Does that mean "$c \prod_j (a_j+b_j)$" or "$\prod_j ((a_j+b_j) c)$"? I would favor the second option. On the other hand, "$f(x) y$" clearly means "$y f(x)$", not "$f(x y)$". But "$\sin(x+y)z$" is still ambiguous since the parenthesis is not always mandatory after $\sin$-like finctions.

Comment: @MichelFioc Lets agree that the notation $c \cdot \Pi _j (a_j +b_j)$ is unambiguous. Note that $\Pi _j (a_j +b_j)$ is just a real number, call it $r$. Then $c \cdot \Pi _j (a_j +b_j) = c \cdot r = r \cdot c = \Pi _j (a_j +b_j)c$.  Also $\sin(x+y)z $ is not ambiguous. The argument to the $\sin$ function is $(x+y)$. The function as a whole is then multiplied by $z$. The parentheses are only left off when there is no chance of confusion.

Comment: @MichelFioc note that when mathematicians write things like $\Pi _j (a_j +b_j)c$ or $\sin (x+y)z$, the parentheses denote an implicit multiplication, written $\cdot$.  Thus they really mean $\Pi _j (a_j +b_j) \cdot c$ or $\sin (x+y) \cdot z$. Also the sigma and product operators  actually are a kind of function. For instance, the sum operator takes in a sequence, which we could view as a vector in $ \mathbb{R} ^n$, and returns a single number (the sum) in $ \mathbb{R}$. Thus $\Sigma: \mathbb{R} ^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short Answer:

The sum $\sum_{j\in J}  a + b +c+\cdots $ is taken over the first term following the $\sum$ operator. That is, everything before the first plus or minus sign. In my example, the first term is $a$. If you want to include more things in the first term, use parentheses. For instance, if you want to sum over the sum of $a$ and $b$ (but not $c$, etc), you write  $\sum_{j\in J}  (a + b) +c+\cdots$

Also, suppose $(x_j)_{j\in J}=x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_j$ is a sequence with domain $J$. It has been pointed out in the comments by SebastianSchoennenbeck, if one wants to take the sum over all numbers $j$ such that the sequence $(x_j)_{j\in J}$ is defined, it is clearer to write $\sum_{j\in J} (x_j + C_1)$ than $\sum_{j} (x_j + C_1)$. Knuth's definition of the $\sum$ operator agrees, stating

> Formally, we write $\sum _{P(j)} x_j$ as an abbreviation for the sum
>   of all terms $x_j$ such that $j$ is an integer satisfying a given
>   property $P(k)$. A 'property $P(k)$' is any statement
>   about $k$ that can be either true or false (Knuth, Concrete Mathematics, 2e, p.23).

Observe that $j\in J$ is a statement, while $j$ is not, thus only $\sum_{j\in J}$ is correct notation.

---

Now, i'll discuss each of your suggestions. Note $\#1=\#3\neq \#2$!!!

1. $\sum_{j\in J} (x_j + C_1) + C_2$

This is the correct notation for taking the sum over the sum of $x_j + C_1$. The parenthesis indicates that (the sum of) both terms $x_j,C_1$ are included in the summand (ie the thing to be summed). Since the $\sum $ operator is linear, we have that:
\begin{align} \sum_{j\in J} (x_j + C_1) + C_2
 &= \sum _{j\in J} x_j +\sum _{j\in J} C_1 +C_2 \\
&= \sum _{j\in J} x_j +|J|\cdot C_1 +C_2  \\
\end{align}

with the last equality because $C_1$ is a constant, and any constant (say $C_1$) plus itself $|J|$ times, = $|J| \cdot C_1$.

2. $[\sum_{j\in J} x_j + C_1] + C_2$

**This notation only takes the sum of $x_j$.** This expression is **not equal to the other two** because here $C_1$ is not in first term ($x_j$) and thus not in the summand. Thus your middle term is only a $C_1$ term instead of a $|J|\cdot C_1$.

This gets to the heart of your question: Only the first term after the $\sum$ is considered to be in the summand (the first term being the stuff before any $+,-$). If we want to take the sum over $x$ terms we enclose them in parentheses.

Writing out some simple sums may help you understand the notation. Suppose we have a sequence $(a_j)=a_1,a_2,a_3$ (whose domain is $J$={1,2,3}), and a constant C.

$$\sum_{j\in J} a_j + C= a_1 + a_2 +a_3 + C$$

Observe that since $C$ is not in the first term, and there are no parentheses, it is not in the summand, and we do not sum over it. In contrast:

\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in J} (a_j + C) &=
 (a_1+C) + (a_2+C) +(a_3 + C)\\
&= \sum_{j\in J} (a_j) + 3C \\
&= \sum_{j\in J} (a_j)+ \sum_{j\in J}(C)
\end{align}

Finally, note that that $\sum _{j\in J} (x_j)$ is just a real number (real numbers are closed under addition), call it $R_1$. Then you have $[\sum_{j\in J} x_j + C_1] + C_2=(R_1+C_1)+C_2$. Of course $R_1+C_2$ is also a real number say $R_2$, thus making these substitutions, you wrote $(R_2)+C_2$. Thus the parentheses are clearly redundant.

3. $[\sum_{j\in J} (x_j + C_1)] + C_2$

This is just #1 with a redundant pair of outer parentheses. That is $\sum_{j\in J} (x_j + C_1)$ is just a real number say $R_3$. Thus you wrote $ (R_3)+C_1$.

References:

Stewart, *Calculus*, 7e, p, A34-A37. 
Knuth, *Concrete Mathematics*, 2e, 21-33.

Comment: Quick note: $\sum_j C_1 \neq j C_1$, since $j$ is the parameter of the sum not the number of terms.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck Good catch. When the index/parameter $j$ has no bounds, are we to assume the sum ranges over all numbers such that the sequence $(x_j)$ is defined? If so, there should be $|dom((x_j))| $ terms in the sum and thus $\sum_j C_1= |dom((x_j))|\cdot C_1$ ?

Comment: That is usually the implied meaning. Generally speaking I would always include the set over which we are taking the sum, e.g. $\sum_{j \in J}$ in which case we get $|J|\cdot C_1$ (which probably implicitly tells us that $J$ is finite).

Comment: $\sum_j C_1\ne jC_1$

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck and Hagen. Knuth agrees with you on the notation Sebastian. I have edited the post to explain the OPs notation for the scope of the sum is ambiguous, changed my notation to follow yours/Knuth's, fixed the algebra, and quoted Knuth's definition of the sum into the answer.

Answer (score 15):

The scope of the series operator is the following term; it encompassed any multiplication (or division).

$$\sum_i \color{blue}{x_iy^i} = \sum_i \color{blue}{y^ix_i}$$

The scope of the series operator is just one term; it ends at a '$+$'.

$$\sum_i \color{blue}{x_iy^i} + z = z+ \sum_i \color{blue}{x_iy^i}$$

Parenthesis may be added just emphasis if you wish; around the term or the whole series.   This is just used to add clarrity.

$$\sum_i \color{blue}{(x_iy^i)}+z ~=~ \left(\sum_i \color{blue}{x_iy^i}\right)+z ~=~ \sum_i \color{blue}{x_iy^i}+z$$

Note enclosing an entires expression in parenthesis does not change the operator precedence within.

$$\left(\sum_i \color{blue}{x_iy^i} + z\right) = \left(z+ \sum_i \color{blue}{x_iy^i}\right)$$

*However*, if such is required, parenthesis are employed to enclose a term which is itself a sum, thusly.

$$\sum_i \color{blue}{\Big(x_iy^i + z_i\Big)} = \sum_i \color{blue}{\Big(z_i+x_iy^i\Big)}$$

---

tl:dr$$\color{silver}[\sum_{i=1}^3 (x_i+C_1)\color{silver}]+C_2 ~{= \color{silver}[(x_1+C_1)+(x_2+C_1)+(x_3+C_1)\color{silver}]+C_2 \\ = (x_1+x_2+x_3)+3 C_1+ C_2}$$

While

$$[\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i+C_1]+C_2 ~{= \big((x_1+x_2+x_3)+C_1\big)+C_2\\= (x_1+x_2+x_3)+C_1+C_2}$$

Comment: This is an excelent answer. Easy to read and to keep as reference for when my students ask about it. The color highlights help a lot.

Comment: Actually it seems the convention is that juxtaposition has higher precedence than summation or products, but that the multiplication symbol has lower precedence. Hence $\sum_{k=1}^n k \sum_{m=1}^n m^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n ( k \sum_{m=1}^n m^2 )$ while $\sum_{k=1}^n k \times \sum_{m=1}^n m^2 = ( \sum_{k=1}^n k ) \times ( \sum_{m=1}^n m^2 )$. Of course, there will always be people who adopt different precedence rules...

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

If the terms carry the index, then it can be implicitly assumed that they are part of the summand, e.g.

$$\sum_{i} a_i+b_i+c=\sum_{i}(a_i+b_i)+c$$
even though it is not clear if $c$ is part of the summand. Here it is assumed not.

Perhaps one could use the [vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)) if one doesn't want the summand to be cluttered with brackets, e.g.
$$\sum_{i} \overline{a_i+b_i+c}+d$$

**Addendum**

One way to think about it is to consider the summand to be the first "object" immediately after the summation sign. "Object" here can be a single term (e.g. $a_i$), a product of two or more terms (e.g. $a_i b_i$), or terms included in brackets (e.g. $(a_i+c)$ ). Other terms are not to be summed.

However, one may choose to intepret a stray indexed summand as implying parentheses e.g. taking
$\displaystyle\sum_i a_i+b+c+d_i$ to mean $\displaystyle\sum_i (a_i+b+c+d_i)$.

Comment: I think this is reasonable advice for interpreting bad notation if you encounter it, but I would not recommend it at all as something you should write yourself.

Comment: No, don't use the vinculum. That is dreadful advice.

Comment: @Rahul - agreed. A useful guide for interpretation, but not for application.

Comment: @TonyK - Haha what do you have against the vinculum?

Comment: Nobody would know what it means. Well, I wouldn't, and I was pretty well trained.

Comment: @TonyK - Better stick to brackets then!

Answer (score 2):

$C_2 + \sum_{i = 1}^n C_1 + x_i$ is not ambiguous, but $C_2 + \sum_i(x_i + C_1)$ seems nicer to me.

What about $C_2 + nC_1 + \sum_i x_i$?

Comment: What if $C_2$ is sum over an index $j$. As I said don't assume it's constant. Maybe I should change the name $C$.

Comment: @konpsych Then, I a line after this would contain the words where $C_2 = \sum_j \dots$ :)

Answer (score 0):

The original problem is that you want to add $C_1$ to the sum. As you have not given a sensible reason why this is desirable/optimal, I think you should avoid it. Instead, write as

$$ \sum_{j} x_j + nC_1 + C_2 $$

You still preserve the $C_i$ ordering (which @Antonie's answer, albeit interesting, does not), and you are not going to confuse **anyone** who is familiar with summation. You hardly ever see expressions where every term in a summation is surrounded by brackets.

Comment: An argument against adding $C_1$ out of the sum is that the set over which j is added may not be easy to enumerate. E.g j  takes values in the set of all primes between $N_1$ and $N_2$.

Comment: @konpsych Good point!